# How to add "onclick" event in wordpress menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

i have created page from wp-admin and i have added that page in to menu. and it's displaying in my website also..

now my question is i want to call **pop() function of javascript** something like this **onclick="pop()**. i don't have any idea how to do it.

i have different 5 menus(pages) but i want to add function only for this menu(page)..

i have searched in google also but didn't get any idea or help.

can you please help me?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger Js files only on certain post using the $post variable.

Here is a sample of how you can implement this in your function.php :

```
function myjavascript_in_wp_head($pid){
   if (is_page('myPAge')) {
       echo "<script>alert('hello world');</script>";
   }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'myjavascript_in_wp_head' );
```

Comment: i am using page here.. how to do in page?

Comment: See edit, the Js will embed only is the page is named `MyPage`

Answer (score 0):

You can check body classess.
By default, wordpress assignes classes to the body to indetify pages/posts

So for example page with ID 155 will have body class page-id-155
Then you can check with jQuery

```
if($('body').hasClass('page-id-155')) {
    //do your staff
}
```